# Average calculator to run python scripts with arguments

Tags: python, average, calculation

I am trying to make a simple average calculation but trying my best to run on CMD.
So far this is what I've came out

```
import sys

myList = [a,b,c]

myList[0] = int(sys.argv[1])

myList[1] = int (sys.argv[2])

myList[2] = int(sys.argv[3])

print 'Average:'  + sum(myList) / len(myList)
```

my question is; how do set a variable in a list to give them a value?

EDIT:

```
   import sys

    myList = [a,b,c]

    a = int(sys.argv[1])

    b = int (sys.argv[2])

    c = int(sys.argv[3])

    print 'Average:'  + sum(myList) / len(myList)
```

whats wrong with this code?

EDIT:

I want to allow users to run this program with three input arguments by passing three values to the program: a, b and c.

Edit:

this is my final edit, anyone can help  me with this

```
import sys

a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])
if a == str or  b == str or c == str:
   print 'Your input is invalid'
else:   
    print 'Average: %.2f ' % ((a + b + c) / 3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the `myList = [a,b,c]` line, and you won't want to use integer division, but the rest seems fine. What are you asking?

Comment: `myList = [int(i) for i in sys.argv[1:4]]`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've edited my code, i hope you understand what i am asking.

Comment: @greatestever Just use the first way without the `myList = [a,b,c]` line. You could probably also just say `myList = list(sys.argv)`, or use `sys.argv` directly if it's already a list. I can't remember what type it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an empty list and use method `append`.

`3 / 2` equals `1` in Python 2 so you want to work with floats.

You can't concatenate floats and strings so you want to use `%` or `format`.

Here is your code after corrections:

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(float(sys.argv[1]))
my_list.append(float(sys.argv[2]))
my_list.append(float(sys.argv[3]))
print 'Average: %s' % (sum(my_list) / len(my_list))
```

Or shorlty:

```
my_list = map(float, sys.argv[1:])
print 'Average: %s' % (sum(my_list) / len(my_list))
```

Or if you want to unpack arguments in separate variables:

```
a, b, c = map(float, sys.argv[1:])
print 'Average: %s' % ((a + b + c) / 3)
```

Comment: well the task that i was given needs to put a,b,c as variable. dont mind if you edit this code base on that.

Comment: may i know from the code you just added how to add if the input numbers are invalid and present an error message. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
import sys
my_list = [float(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
print('Average: {}'.format(sum(my_list) / len(my_list))
```

`[float(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]` is a list-comprehension (one-liner `for` that returns a list). It parse args into `float` (`float(arg)`) and loop from the second element of `sys.argv` (first is name of you script file).

Float type is forced because Python trunk results of division if both numerator and denominator are `int`.

*Btw, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) required snake_case (`my_list`, not `myList`) and string concat should never be done with `+`, but with `format` or `join()`.*